# Creating a table at run time by stored procedure is executed on SQL Server successfully but run time error on application execution

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, syntax-error, runtime-error

SQL Server stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[tblfrends] 
    @TABLENAME nvarchar
AS
BEGIN-- use body wrappers around whole body
  SET NOCOUNT ON; -- put this at the beginning - no point in setting it at the end

  DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX); -- dynamic SQL should always be Unicode

  SELECT @SQL = 'CREATE TABLE' + QUOTENAME(@TABLENAME) + '(`friend_one` INT,
                                                                `friend_two` INT,
                                                                `status` nvarchar(10) ,
                                                   PRIMARY KEY (`friend_one`,`friend_two`);'

  EXEC sp_executesql @sql; -- instead of EXEC(@sql)
END
```

C# code:

```
public void createtable()
{
    SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("tblfrends", access.sqlConnection);
    sqlCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@TABLENAME",System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    sqlCommand.Parameters["@TABLENAME"].Value = Name.Text;

    access.crud(sqlCommand);

    if (sqlCommand.UpdatedRowSource > 0)
    {
        Response.Write("frend table");
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("tayn tayn fishhh");
    }
}
```

Error at runtime:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Incorrect syntax near '`'.

Comment: Don't use MySQL quotes for SQL Server, in SQL Server you either use the double quote or square brackets to quote object names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No the syntax of your stored procedure is wrong.

This should be the correct text

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[tblfrends] 
                @TABLENAME nvarchar(255) 
AS 
BEGIN

    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SELECT @SQL = N'CREATE TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@TABLENAME) + 
                  N' (friend_one INT, friend_two INT, status nvarchar(10),' + 
                  N' PRIMARY KEY (friend_one,friend_two))'
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql

END
```

**First** you need to specify the size of the parameter @TableName received by the sp otherwise it is assumed to be one char long and you get a table name with only the first letter.

**Second** You miss a closing parenthesis after the PRIMARY KEY declaration.

Finally, not really a problem to result in failure but nevertheless..., add spaces before and after the QUOTENAME command, and note that SQL Server doesn't want backticks around the fields names.

Comment: tank you  brother. it's help full

Answer (score 0):

This is what your @SQL variable becomes:

```
CREATE TABLE[s](`friend_one` INT,
       `friend_two` INT,
        `status` nvarchar(10) ,
        PRIMARY KEY (`friend_one`,`friend_two`);
```

As you can see, there is multiple problems. Wrong single quotes and missing parenthesis. Also you are trying to add multiple primary keys.

Try change your stored procedure like this:

```
SELECT @SQL = 'CREATE TABLE' + QUOTENAME(@TABLENAME) + '(friend_one INT PRIMARY KEY,
       friend_two INT,
       status nvarchar(10))'
```

So your @SQL variable will become something like:

```
CREATE TABLE[s](friend_one INT PRIMARY KEY,
                friend_two INT,
                status nvarchar(10))
```

Comment: tank you  brother. it's help full